# Fixing tqdm progress bar when batching data in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tqdm

I have a code that will have to handle a very big array.

This array does not fit into my pc's RAM memory, so I have to batch it so that I can handle everything.

However, my `tqdm` bar prints every batch I have in a new line instead of appending all the results.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp


def chunks(lst, size):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), size):
        yield lst[i:i + size]


def foo(x):
    a,b = x
    return a+b


def main():
    np.random.seed(1234)
    
    a = np.random.rand(100)
    b = np.random.rand(100)

    size_of_chunk = 1000
    vals = list(itertools.product(a,b))
                
    with mtp.Pool(processes = 4) as pool:
        s = 0
        for chunk in chunks(vals, size_of_chunk):
            results = list( 
                            tqdm (pool.imap(foo, chunk), total = len(vals))
                          )
            
            s += np.sum(results)
                
        return s
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = main()
```

I would like to know 3 things:

1 - Is this the correct and most efficient way of batching the data for parallel processing?

2 - How can I fix the `tqdm` bar such that every batch gets into the same progress bar.

3- Any program to check the memory footprint of a python script running in parallel?

Best Regards

Comment: Try [MPIRE (MultiProcessing Is Really Easy)](https://github.com/sybrenjansen/mpire) - it comes with built-in tqdm support

Answer (score 2):

You are asking 3 seemingly unrelated questions, which should be 3 separate posts. But I will try to answer your first two.

The `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap` method supports its own chunking, which should be used here in the following fashion for the simplest solution to get a single progress bar and to efficiently use memory. This method supports a lazy evaluation of its past iterable. But now that we are not doing our own explciit chunking, once you convert a generator such as `itertools.product(a, b)` to a `list` instance, you are defeating this lazy evaluation and the entire 100 * 100 elements generated must be stored in memory. You *might* have to convert such a generator to a list just to compute the total number of elements, which you need to know for use with `tqdm`. But that is not the case here.

Function `compute_chunksize` computes a *chunksize* argument to be used with `imap` more or less the same way method `map` would compute it if no *chunksize* argument were specified, but you might wish to experiment with different *chunksize* values.

Also, you should use method `imap_unordered` since (1) it is more efficient (2) the order of returned values is not important for addition and (3) the progress bar will advance any time any result is calculated and returned (actually results are also returned in chunks, but now the order in which a chunk is calculated does not matter -- as soon as a chunk has been calculated those results will be returned).

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp

def foo(x):
    a, b = x
    return a + b

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def main():
    np.random.seed(1234)

    N = 100
    iterable_size = N * N
    POOL_SIZE = 4

    a = np.random.rand(N)
    b = np.random.rand(N)

    vals = itertools.product(a, b)
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(iterable_size, POOL_SIZE)

    with mtp.Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE) as pool:
        s = 0
        for result in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(foo, vals, chunksize=chunksize), total=iterable_size):
            s += result
        return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

If you want to do your own *efficient* chunking that uses lazy evaluation (**and may offer better performance than using implicit chunking with the *chunksize* argument** at the cost of slightly more complicated code), then:

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp

def chunks(iterable, size_of_chunk):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        while True:
            chunk = []
            for _ in range(size_of_chunk):
                chunk.append(next(iterator))
            yield chunk
    except StopIteration:
        if chunk:
            yield chunk

def foo(chunk):
    s = 0
    for a, b in chunk:
        s += a + b
    return s

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def main():
    np.random.seed(1234)

    N = 100
    POOL_SIZE = 4

    iterable_size = N * N
    a = np.random.rand(N)
    b = np.random.rand(N)

    vals = itertools.product(a, b)
    size_of_chunk = compute_chunksize(iterable_size, POOL_SIZE)
    n_chunks, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, size_of_chunk)
    if remainder:
        n_chunks += 1

    with mtp.Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE) as pool:
        s = 0
        for result in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(foo, chunks(vals, size_of_chunk)), total=n_chunks):
            s += result

        return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```